# Location is Returning null LocationManager.getlastlocation Gps Provider

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have searched and implemented every way out there to get my location. But the location is always null, no matter what i do. It's null. My application is almost complete and this is the only thing which is making a problem here is my code.

```
    public Location getlocation() {
    Location loc = null;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
      loc =  lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
    }
return loc;
}
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    setmap(googleMap);
}

public void setmap(final GoogleMap map) {
    googlemap = map;
    if (googlemap != null) {
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CustomAlarm.satellite, false)) {
            googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        } else {
            googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }
        if(getlocation() == null){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You don't live on this earth or Location null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Before commenting please note this.

1- I am debugging on my cell phone samsung j1 api level 19.

2- already enabled location and gps.

3- tried locating my location in googlemaps.

4- also enabled Google location history.

But nothing please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same problem once.
I resolved it by requesting location updates.

[Google recommendations about it](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

After some time, location was caught.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting your location inside this

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { }
```

That means if the permissions are **NOT** granted.

The line `loc =  lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` gets never executed when the permission **IS** granted (which it probably is) so will stay the same value as you assigned it earlier `Location loc = null;` so null.

You should change the if statement to

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

Which means if the location permission **IS** granted then give me the location.

Comment: Then `lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` returns false. Can't you check if the `loc =  lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` line is getting executed at all?

Comment: Just added a check statement it's not false.

Comment: So the line `loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` gets executed?

Comment: But it wasnt before right? Because you changed **!=** to **==** in the first if statement, so I don't know how you can be so sure if you didn't check it back then... Anyways the only way `loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` will return null is when `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` is not enabled.